Quarto tbl-cap-location not going to top with gtsummary
I am very confused why I can't get the table caption to go to the top when using quarto in RStudio

    ---
    title: "test caption location"
    format: html
    ---
    
    ```{r}

    #| tbl-cap-location: top
    
    data(mtcars)
    
    library(gtsummary)
    library(knitr)
    
    mtcars %>%
      select(mpg, cyl, disp) %>%
      tbl_summary() |> 
      modify_caption("This is a test")
    ```

It seems super straight forward, but after the render it is always on the bottom:

Is it something being out of date or something?

Can't reproduce your issue using gtsummary 2.0.3 and quarto 1.2.335. Works fine both when rendering in quarto or when I run as a script: https://i.sstatic.net/rUdThK5k.png

But I'm not able to place the caption at the bottom using tbl-cap-location: bottom. :D

I checked and I am using 2.0.3 for gtsummary and 1.4.549 for quarto

Just updated to quarto 1.5.57, and that seemed to work :), but now I am having the same problem where I can't change it bottom, but for some reason it does work for margin, so still very confusing

Haha. Thx for reminding me that I should update my version of quarto. And yes. I checked with "margin" too. Not sure whether the issue with bottom/top is on the side of gtsummary or quarto.

I needed to update Quarto from the website. As soon as I ran the current version, it moved the table caption location to the top. However, now the table caption can no longer go to the bottom. A possible bug?
